# need to compile gzstream files on windows

Tags: c#, php, windows-mobile, compression

I need to compile [gzstream](http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/compgeom/gzstream/) the 2 test files **test_gzip.c** and **test_gunzip.c** to produce 2 .exe files ,I've done that on ubuntu by the make command which ran the Makefile and built the 2 executable files which is not compatible with windows they must be .exe so anybody have a solution for this problem specially that i don't want to use any other zlib library as the compression itself in zlib methods is different from language to another

Answer (score 0):

There is a make version for windows from GNU. Just google for "GNU Make Windows" and you'll find it. That should allow you to run the make stuff through the command line on Windows.

You can also try looking at minGW, which is a windows port of the GCC compiler. I believe it comes with a special command prompt that accepts commands such as "ls" from linux and "make" allowing you to compile code that was ment for linux systems on Windows as well.